# Earliest quote by a Church Father on how saints can add their merit to the treasury which can then be applied to others

Tags: catholicism, early-church, church-fathers, communion-of-saints, merit

#### About Treasury of Merit

The teaching of the [treasury of merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasury_of_merit) (*GotQuestions* article [here](https://www.gotquestions.org/treasury-of-merit.html)) in connection to the communion of saints and indulgences is explained in CCC 1476-1477 and is based on the Catholic interpretation of Matt 6:19-20, 1 Cor 12:26, and Col 1:24.  Two apologetics article, [Dr. Taylor Marshall's article](https://taylormarshall.com/2006/06/indulgences-and-treasury-of-merit.html) and  [Bryan Cross's article](https://www.calledtocommunion.com/2011/01/indulgences-the-treasury-of-merit-and-the-communion-of-saints/) (from his *Called to Communion* website), address frequent misunderstanding by Protestants.

But neither articles, nor the CCC, nor the Catholic Encyclopedia articles on [Indulgences](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07783a.htm) and [Merit](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10202b.htm) mention the patristic source of the teaching on **how the saints' merits are added to a treasury** from which the merit becomes available to be applied to another believer **instead of simply a reward** for themselves (i.e. the saints who obtained the merit through their good work on earth).

#### Insufficient pointers

1. There is only one oblique reference to St. Cyprian's defending the *lapsi* against the Novatians:

   > St. Cyprian, therefore, believed that the merits of the martyrs could be applied to less worthy Christians by way of vicarious satisfaction, and that such satisfaction was acceptable in the eyes of God as well as of the Church.
   >
   > (*Source*: [Epistle 13](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/050613.htm) of St. Cyprian of Carthage, AD 250, referred to in the *Indulgences* encyclopedia article)

   which is not that convincing because of lack of general application (i.e. non-martyr saints and non-*lapsi* situations).
2. I find that Eastern Orthodox also has a concept of Treasury of Merits **BUT** only God has the power to distribute the gifts.  The justification for this teaching is from **liturgical text** (see 2018 blog article from the *Orthodox West Journal* website: [Regarding the Merits of the Saints](https://journal.orthodoxwestblogs.com/2018/02/09/regarding-the-merits-of-the-saints/)).

#### My question

**Where can I see the earliest clear statement from the early church period, that the saints' merit is available to be applied to another?**

The answer can also include:

- The first Church Fathers who interpret Matt 6:19-20, 1 Cor 12:26, and Col 1:24 along the lines of modern Catholic teaching of the treasury of merit.
- If the Catholic church also bases this teaching from early church liturgy, please provide the quote **linking** the liturgical text to a church council or a church father teaching.

Comment: I think treasury-of-merit deserves its own tag. I'm not sure if supererogation should be a separate one, but probably (though that's more for other questions.)

Comment: @curiousdannii I leave it to your judgment.  There were only 2 under `merit` before I started retagging.

Comment: Haha, I was commenting instead of acting because I thought your expertise would be valuable here!

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm proposing to treat the 3 concepts of merit, treasury-of-merit and supererogation under `merit` to emphasize the interconnection and because there are not that many questions.  See my [tag info](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/merit/info).